# Creating a COM port out of a ttyUSB port in Ubuntu

Tags: c#, windows, ubuntu, usb

### The Question

I'm having to work with a rather awkward API at the moment which **insists** on me giving the address of a device, linked via USB port, in the form **COM***. However, on the **Ubuntu** machine on which I'm working, and have to use, if I plug in this device it will automatically be assigned an address in the form **/dev/ttyUSB***.

Given that I can't modify the source code of the API - which I would dearly like to do! - what is the least painful way getting the API to talk to said device?

### Extra Detail

An example of how to use the API from the manual:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using com.caen.RFIDLibrary;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CAENRFIDReader MyReader = new CAENRFIDReader();
      MyReader.Connect(CAENRFIDPort.CAENRFID_RS232, "COM3");
      CAENRFIDLogicalSource MySource = MyReader.GetSource("Source_0");
      CAENRFIDTag[] MyTags = MySource.InventoryTag();

      if (MyTags.Length > 0)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < MyTags.Length; i++)
        {
          String s = BitConverter.ToString(MyTags[i].GetId());
          Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Press a key to end the program.");
      Console.ReadKey();
      MyReader.Disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

The line `MyReader.Connect(CAENRFIDPort.CAENRFID_RS232, "COM3");` is where I'm running into problems.

A little later in the manual, it states that the `Connect` method is to have two parameters:

> *ConType*: The communication link to use for the connection.
>
> *Address*: Depending on ConType parameter: IP address for TCP/IP communications ("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"), COM port for RS232 communications ("COMx"), an index for USB communications (not yet supported).

### Bonus Question

The API in question seems to have been written on the assumption that it would be run on a Windows machine. (It's in C#.) The COM* format seems to be favoured - I'm happy to be corrected on this point - by Windows architectures, whereas Ubuntu seems to favour the ttyUSB* format. Assuming that I can funnel the data from my device from a ttyUSB* port to a COM* port, will the API actually be able to find said data? Or will it incorrectly follow the default Windows path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the new information i suspect you can just give the ttyUSB as the parameter, mono will handle the connection correctly. However the same caution for the line endings below still applies. You might also consider making the parameter a command-line parameter thus making your code run on any platform by being able to supply the COM/USB through the command line parameters. I see no other issues using this code. Did you try it yet?

PS: i think your confusion is actually the statement usb id's are not supported yet, i suspect that is because the library relies on a (text-based) serial connection wich are fundamentally different from direct USB connections (wich drivers normally handle) that handle the connection in a more direct way. The ttyUSB ports on linux however DO represent the (UART) serial connections the same way as windows COM-ports, these are not direct USB connections.

Some handy info about the differences: https://rfc1149.net/blog/2013/03/05/what-is-the-difference-between-devttyusbx-and-devttyacmx/

**Old answer**

I am assuming you run this program on Mono?

Mono expects the path to the port, so COM* will not do. You could try creating a symlink named COM* to the ttyUSB*. Preferrably located in the environment directory. Once you get them linked the program should see no difference. However line endings in the data/program might be different than on windows. If the device expects CRLF and the program uses Environment.NewLine you might get unexpected behaviour too. It might just be easier if you have the permission/rights to edit the assembly with recompilation tools.

Comment: I am indeed running this in Mono! I think you've got the wrong end of the stick slightly - this is my fault - in that my code doesn't do anything with the port address *directly*. Instead, I pass the port address to an object from the API, which then does some voodoo on it. Since said API is not open-source, I can neither see what exactly is going on nor make any modifications. I'll add some more detail to my question just now, in order to make things a bit clearer.

Comment: Tom, did you try making the symbolic link?  It would probably work.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this again. Unfortunately, one thing that I know definitely **won't** work is subsituting "/dev/ttyUSB0" or just "ttyUSB0" for "COM3". Either of these cause the program to throw an exception. I'm out of the office today and tomorrow, but I may experiment a bit more on Wednesday. In any case, you've provided a very fine answer, even though it hasn't solved my particular problem.

Comment: @TomHosker I am determined to see this actually solved :), if I understand correctly you are trying to run this on linux, you need to substitute the "COM3" in your example *to* "/dev/ttyUSB0" or whatever the number is you get when you attach the device. If that throws an error like you say, it might be useful to attach the error so we can determine what is wrong. Friendly Regards.

Comment: Okay, well [here's a link to the repository I'm working on](https://github.com/tomhosker/proton-cs-min) right now. The file "ProgramUSB.cs" file is where the magic happens (or is supposed to happen). I've also put in a screenshot of the error that I'm running into; it's the only image file in there. I've thrown in a couple of manuals for good measure, too. Let's smash this!

Comment: Note that ProgramEthernet.cs works exactly as intended, on both Windows and Ubuntu. ProgramUSB.cs only works on Windows; on Ubuntu it throws the exception shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes i have bad news for you that library wasn't made for linux and does some stupid check on the port you give it. I suggest you try the symlink approach instead. (the library searches for "/DEV/TTYUSB0" so i suspect it somewhere does a `ToUpper()` on the port. A symlink COM0 to the usb and then using COM0 could work.

Comment: Cool. Well that at least is helpful to know. I'll try the symlink thing just now, and update you once I have any news.

Comment: Okay. I'm not having much luck with symbolic links either. I've installed Wine, and created a symbolic link called "COM3" in ".wine/dosdevices" to "/dev/ttyUSB0". I've also changed the constant in ProgramUSB.cs from "/dev/ttyUSB0" to "COM3" and recompiled. However, when I try to run either "wine ProgramUSB.exe" or "./ProgramUSB.exe", I get the same error as before. Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using wine? You are running mono wich runs natively on Linux, so just create a link either symbolic or hard link (try the other if one does not work) with the `ln` command (kindof like mklink in windows). Check https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-hard-links-with-ln-command/ how to create it.

Comment: BUT WHERE DO I PUT THE SYMLINK?! Aaaaargh! But seriously, creating a symlink is easy; getting this library - which I'm roped into using - to recognise and listen to that symlink seems impossible.

Comment: Just run `ln /dev/ttyUSB0 COM3` inside the executable folder and then run it on mono without wine. If it doesn't work delete the old link and add the -s parameter to the same command to create a symbolic instead of hardlink